# Sort String array in custom order

Tags: c#, sorting, arrays

I want to sort a fixed set of strings like "Text files", "Image files", "Audio files", "Video files", "Application Files", "Other files" in a string array in the same order I have mentioned.

Example1, if my string array input is like this

```
inputval[0] = "Other files";
inputval[1] = "Image files";
inputval[2] = "Text files";
```

my output array should have values like this

```
outputval[0] = "Text files";
outputval[1] = "Image files";
outputval[2] = "Other files";
```

Example 2, if my string array input is like this

```
inputval[0] = "Application files";
inputval[1] = "Image files";
inputval[2] = "Video files";
```

my output array should have values like this

```
outputval[0] = "Image files";
outputval[1] = "Video files";
outputval[2] = "Application files";
```

Please can somebody help me in achieving this

Comment: On what basis do you want to display that arrays?

Comment: Do you mean that the `Image files`, `Text files`... are types and not strings?

Comment: Image files, Text files are string values.. basically I will get user input as "Other files;Image files;Text files;" or with any other combination which Im splitting into a string array (Split(';'). but once I split I want the array values to be in the same order as I have mentioned. Please let me know if u r still not clear?

Comment: It will be good if you associate a serial order number with each array element and sort the array on that number

Comment: I think you should answer to the first comment of @Nikhil Agrawal. What if on your example there is an extra string 'Video files'?

Comment: People reading this question should note, while the posted answers will work, and they aren't too bad if the expected input is small, they will be very inefficient if the number of possible sorted values is large. A better approach, using a dictionary of sort indexes, can be found at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since not very much is clear from what you want. So i have taken into consideration that there will be no repetitions in `inputval`.

```
string[] fixed_array =  { "Text files", "Image files", "Audio files", 
                        "Video files", "Application Files", "Other files" };
```

Let us say

```
inputval[0] = "Other files";
inputval[1] = "Image files";
inputval[2] = "Text files";
```

Do this

```
string[] outputval =
          fixed_array.Select(x => inputval.Contains(x) ? x : "-1")
                     .Where(x => x != "-1").ToArray();
```

So `outputval` will be

```
outputval[0] = "Text files";
outputval[1] = "Image files";
outputval[2] = "Other files";
```

Comment: use `StringComparer` `IgnoreCase` with `Contains` method

Comment: @user671218 you have `Application files` with simple `f` in files but fixed_array with `Application Files` with capital `F`

Comment: How to do the same with objects? Any ideas?

Comment: @Azimuth: You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method of your class.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I implemented that by creating comparer class :)

Comment: That is another way, basically all we need is a way to compare objects not just on reference check.

Answer (score 8):

This crude implementation using `IComparer<string>` supplied to `Array.Sort` works. There are various potential shortcomings, but I'll leave these to you (like strings needing to match exactly, otherwise they won't sort correctly).

It simply uses an internal list of strings that represent the correct order, and then compares their ordinals in that list with each other.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication61
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] files = new[] { "Audio Files", "Text Files", "Video Files", "Other Files", "Application Files" };
            Array.Sort(files, new FileComparer());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class FileComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        static List<string> OrderedFiles = new List<string> { "Text Files", "Image Files", "Audio Files", "Video Files", "Application Files", "Other Files" };

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            int xi = OrderedFiles.IndexOf(x);
            int yi = OrderedFiles.IndexOf(y);

            if (xi > yi)
                return 1;

            if (xi < yi)
                return -1;

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement an `ICompare` and then you can use `OrderBy` with an `ICompare` to get your custom sort.  Check [MSDN ICompare article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422)

I.e. something like,

```
public class MyCompare : ICompare<string>
{
    // Because the class implements IComparer, it must define a 
    // Compare method. The method returns a signed integer that indicates 
    // whether s1 > s2 (return is greater than 0), s1 < s2 (return is negative),
    // or s1 equals s2 (return value is 0). This Compare method compares strings. 
    public int Comapre(string s1, string s2)
    {
        // custom logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just have the strings with numbers appended in the beginning and add it to a sorted list..

like  "0,Text files", "1,Image files", "2,Audio files", "3,Video files", "4,Application Files", "4,Other files"

and then while using remove the string before the ","..